# there are too many leading `super` keywords

Tags: rust, module

I am learning rust(v1.54), Now I want to use `schema.rs` which was located in the root directory of my project from the file `main.rs`, the folder structure looked like this:

[image]

I want to use the module at the root source folder `scheme.rs` in `main.rs`, and I tried this in the `main.rs` file:

```
use super::schema::posts;

fn main(){

}
```

but it seems that it did not work.

```
~/Documents/GitHub/reddwarf_music on  develop! ⌚ 17:40:41
$ cargo build                                                                                                                                                                             ‹ruby-2.7.2›
   Compiling reddwarf_music v0.1.0 (/Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/reddwarf_music)
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: there are too many leading `super` keywords
  --> src/main.rs:11:5
   |
11 | use super::schema::posts;
   |     ^^^^^ there are too many leading `super` keywords
```

I've search the Internet and did not find anything about it. What should I do to make it work as expected? I also tried to use crete:

```
use crate::schema::posts;
```

the error output:

```
~/Documents/GitHub/reddwarf_music on  develop! ⌚ 17:48:23
$ cargo build                                                                                                                                                                             ‹ruby-2.7.2›
   Compiling reddwarf_music v0.1.0 (/Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/reddwarf_music)
error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate::schema`
  --> src/main.rs:11:12
   |
11 | use crate::schema::posts;
   |            ^^^^^^ could not find `schema` in the crate root

warning: unused `#[macro_use]` import
 --> src/main.rs:2:1
  |
2 | #[macro_use] 
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_imports)]` on by default

error: aborting due to previous error; 1 warning emitted

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
error: could not compile `reddwarf_music`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
(base)
```

this is my `schema.rs` file:

```
table! {
    posts (id) {
        id -> Int4,
        title -> Varchar,
        body -> Text,
        published -> Bool,
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `use crate::schema::*;` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of rust are you using? I was able to find other references to E0433 with this same error message, but rust's documentation lists [a different error for E0433](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0433).

`use super::super::schema::*;` should work fine, as can be seen with this code ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0dc76b5418cd5076fe4a6882d518c088)):

```rust
mod schema {
    pub fn schema_test() {
        println!("Success!");
    }
}

mod biz {
    pub mod music {
        use super::super::schema::*;

        pub fn music_test() {
            schema_test();
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    biz::music::music_test();
}
```

Are you able to call the code using `use crate::schema::*` instead? If not, make sure your modules are set up properly and all files are part of the same crate.